# Communicating C++ header file and source files with Windows Form

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

I am building a windows form app where I need this youtube header and source file ([for context](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTxllHdfUq4fewZGVFPhzbmHTQC2UH7PJ)) to communicate with a button in a windows form, I am fairly new to this as I just started this a few weeks ago, I already have this cpp file for my button;

```
//i made this separate file because the windows form header file is flooded with system generated codes already
ButtonHandler.cpp

#include "pch.h" 
#include "Main.h"

void MovieRentalSystem::Main::btn_clientAddReg_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
     //I need to call the linked list into here
     DataList::DataList() { //(1) This is the first error I got
           f_Data = NULL;
           currentData = NULL;
           temp = NULL;
     }
}
```

So I've been following the tutorials mentioned, this is the header file I made

```
LinkedList.h
#pragma once

ref class DataList {
private:
    typedef struct fork { //(2) this is the second error I got
        int data;
        fork* nextData;
    }* dataPointer;
    dataPointer f_Data;
    dataPointer currentData;
    dataPointer temp;
public:
    DataList();
    void addFork(int addFork);
    void delFork(int delFork);
    void p_list();
};
```

Errors:

(1) `DataList::DataList() {` is expecting a `;`

(2) `struct` is throwing "a standard class cannot be nested in a managed class" just by adding a `ref` because of Tomashu's answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885007/how-to-get-c-class-to-communicate-with-windows-form-textbox)

Maybe, I'm just being stoopid for trying them to communicate or is there a better way in creating a `LinkedList` or `List` using `System::Collections::Generic;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include the header file properly and you are missing a semicolon:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

void MovieRentalSystem::Main::btn_clientAddReg_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
     //I need to call the linked list into here
     // the call is also wrong, you want to create a variable here I guess
     auto datalist = gcnew DataList() {
           f_Data = NULL;
           currentData = NULL;
           temp = NULL;
     }; // <-- is missing
}
```

The second answer is straight-forward as it tells you that a standard class cannot be part of your managed class. You only can hold pointers (and native types) in managed classes:

```
LinkedList.h
#pragma once


typedef struct fork { //(2) this is the second error I got
    int data;
    fork* nextData;
} dataFork;

ref class DataList {
private:
    dataFork* f_Data;
    dataFork* currentData;
    dataFork* temp;
public:
    DataList();
    void addFork(int addFork);
    void delFork(int delFork);
    void p_list();
};
```